# Anjular JS and directives, ng-repeat and template binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to anjular so forgive me if I get some of the terminology wrong.

I've created a simplified example below where I'm trying to get a template in a directive to bind in a ng-repeat.  If you update the input then the simple {{list.name}} gets updated but the {{formattedtext}} doesn't change.

How do I get formatted text to reflect the correct value?

Html

```
<div ng-repeat="list in List" style="border: 1px solid;">
    <list-item>
    </list-item>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="list in List" style="border: 1px solid;">
    <input ng-model="list.name" />
</div>
```

app.js

```
referenceController.$inject = ['$scope'];

var app = angular.module('app',[]).controller('referenceController', referenceController);

app.directive("listItem", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: false,
        template: "<div>Yo {{formattedText}} {{list.name}}</div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.formattedText = scope.list.name + ' (' + scope.list.abbreviation + ')';
        }
   }
});
```

referenceController.js

```
function referenceController($scope) {
    $scope.List = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Name1', abbreviation:'1'},
        { id: 2, name: 'Name2', abbreviation: '2'},
        { id: 3, name: 'Name3', abbreviation: '3'},
        { id: 4, name: 'Name4', abbreviation: '4'}
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to watch the value in your directive:

```
referenceController.$inject = ['$scope'];

var app = angular.module('app',[]).controller('referenceController', referenceController);

app.directive("listItem", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: false,
    template: "<div>Yo {{formattedText}} {{list.name}}</div>",
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var formatText = function(value){
        scope.formattedText = value + ' (' + scope.list.abbreviation + ')';
      }

      formatText(scope.list.name)
      scope.$watch('list.name',formatText)
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

`formattedText` is not that difficult to derive so you can just put it in the template:

```
template: "<div>Yo {{list.name}} ({{list.abbreviation}}) {{list.name}}</div>"
```

Comment: I should have added the template was a cut down version to demonstrate the problem and the real implementation is more complex.